# Using PHP to move files between cPanel accounts on the same server

Tags: php, cpanel

We recently upgraded our server to cPanel 78 and migrated from EA3 to EA4. Our server only has two sites on it, and prior to the upgrade we could use PHP scripts to copy files between the two sites using PHP's file_exists() and copy() functions.

We could use the file_exists() function to grab files from site1 and migrate them to site2 using code similar to this:

```
$current_path = '/home/site1/public_html/uploads';
$new_path = '/home/site2/public_html/uploads';

if(file_exists($current_path.'/v2n62l6v.jpg')) {
    echo 'File exists: true' . "\n\n";
    copy($current_path.'/v2n62l6v.jpg', $new_path.'/2020/03/30/v2n62l6v.jpg');
} else {
    echo 'File exists: false' . "\n\n";
}
```

This code also creates new directories and sets the permissions to 0755.

After the upgrade, when we attempt to execute the script, we are greeted with this error:

```
File exists: true
Warning: copy(/home/site2/public_html/uploads/2020/03/30/v2n62l6v.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/site2/public_html/move.php on line 15
```

We are able to move the files if we set the permissions to the folders to 0777, but I would prefer to not have to change all of the folder permissions (there are 10s of thousands).

Any ideas on where to start or what settings may have changed during the upgrade to either EA or cPanel/WHM?

Site is using:

PHP 5.5 (ea-php55)
DSO PHP Handler
CENTOS 6.10
cPanel v78.0.47

I am happy to provide any other information to help trouble shoot this issue.

Thanks so much for any/all help.

Comment: Why not use SSH terminal for this?

Comment: @KeralPatel - Even attempting to use terminal to execute the scripts results in the same outcome, unless you are suggesting a different approach through SSH?

Comment: I think they are saying using PHP to move files around is crazy, and I would agree. Doing this from the shell, or even with some file management tool, would be a better approach. In any case - are the ownership and permissions the same on the 2 paths?  Does the user running the PHP have permissions to write there? Does `copy()` really create the target dirs if they don't exist? [The docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) don't mention this but [the comments say it does not](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php#62807).

Comment: @Don'tPanic - I wanted to use PHP because there was some processing I wanted to do with each of the images while I move, based on some variables from a database. Right now, I have around 750k images in a single directory in `site1` and I wanted to move the photos to a more appropriate path that relates to the owner in `site2` and segment out the folders. Maybe the better approach is just to do the mass move from `site1` to `site2`, then run our scripts to move the files to their new homes. Permissions/Owners are different on the two sites, just on the same server.

Comment: OK, fair enough. You say the owners are different, but your question does not describe anything about what you've done to allow user1 to write to user2's directories? Which suggests that is the problem. `755` means owner has permission to write, everyone else can read + execute. User2 would not be able to write to a dir owned by user1 which has 755 permissions (and vice versa). If you want this as a permanent solution, maybe add both users to a common group, and give that group write permissions to the dir. Or maybe do your processing to a temp location owned by user1 as user1, then move.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that it is CentOS so the following should work

```
<?php
$current_path = '/home/site1/public_html/uploads';
$new_path = '/home/site2/public_html/uploads';
//Below command will copy paste all folders recursively
shell_exec("cp -r $current_path $new_path");
echo "All Done";
?>
```

If the above one doesn't works for some reasons then try going to the SSH terminal directly and run that shell command with your paths.

As you mentioned in comments that you want to further process the files that could be done on site2 itself once all files are there you could scandir/is_dir to scan and process files. But that is different topic.

Answer (score -1):

If you really need to do this you have to make sure php user owns both sites files - apparently this is not your case.

Alternatively you can use root user to copy files preserving ownership and permission or changing their owner and permission at the destination accordingly.

One other option is to umask user privileges before your operation; Is strongly recommended to revert umask value after operation is completed:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php

Ex:

```
$old = umask(0);
//your operation here
umask($old);
```